# show alert using jQuery-Impromptu if elements value is empty or zero

Tags: jquery, alert, show, element, impromptu

I want to popup alert if elements values are empty or zero.
I want to use Impromptu for that.
here is example of Impromptu:

http://jsfiddle.net/hGRtH/

and my input elements are:

```
<select name="side_room_type" id="room_type" onchange="return getAdultRoom(this.value)" class="input-medium"><option value="0">Select Room Type</option><option value="5">Family Room</option><option value="7">Seaside Rooms</option></select>

<input type="hidden" name="side_check_in_date" onchange="return getAdultRoom(this.value)" id="side_check_in_date" value="">

<select name="side_adults" id="adults" class="input-medium"><option value="">Select Adults</option></select>
```

How can I use Impromptu for alerts?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A rough assumption of what you want:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-impromptu.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" type="text/css" href="jquery-impromptu.css" />
<form id="frm">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#frm").on('submit', function(e){
        if($("#name").val() == ""){
            showPrompt('Please insert name', 'this is the title');
            $("#name").focus();
            e.preventDefault();   
        }
    })

    function showPrompt(msg, title){
        $.prompt(msg, {
            title: title
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Niloy! Thanks for reply. I want to say that my javascript knowledge is not very good. I want to show this alert on form submit using Impromptu. But your example is not similar to what I want. I don't know how to check values and show Impromptu's alert as in jsfiddle link.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>   <script type="text/javascript">
> $(function(){
>         $("#frm").on('submit', function(e){
>             if($("#name").val() == ""  || $("#name").val() == "0"){
>                 showPrompt();
>                 $("#name").focus();
>                 e.preventDefault();   
>             }
>         })
>
>         function showPrompt(msg, title){
>             var tourSubmitFunc = function(e,v,m,f){
>           if(v === -1){
>               $.prompt.prevState();
>               return false;
>           }
>           else if(v === 1){
>               $.prompt.nextState();
>               return false;
>           }
> },
> tourStates = [
>   {
>       title: 'Title',
>       html: 'text of jQuery Impromptu?',
>       buttons: { Done: 2 },
>       focus: 1,
>       position: { container: '#name', x: 30, y: 30, width: 200, arrow: 'tc' },
>       submit: tourSubmitFunc
>   }
> ];
> $.prompt(tourStates);
>
>         }
>     });
>       </script>
> ```

This worked for me.