# Check if input text is filled and prompt an alert if not filled in

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, input, field

I need to check if 3 fields have been filled in on a form. I am using the following code - instead of click event I am using mouseover, otherwise it will reload the page:
I followed the suggestions from [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18824304/jquery-check-if-input-text-value-is-empty-and-prompt-an-alert)

```
$('#dnn_ctr503_DynamicForms_lnkSave').on('mouseover',function()
{
    if( $('#dnn_ctr503_DynamicForms_TBR_GUID35b841a2-5019-4cb0-9041-1204c90e5bebEmail').val().length === 0 ) {
        alert('warning');
    }
});
```

How could I insert 2 more fields in the code please.
So if any of these 3 fields are not filled in the warning message will show up.
Thank you.

Comment: You can just add a `required` to the fields which are required, i.e. `<input type="text" name="myName" required />`

Comment: Instead of this you can do the validation while `submitting` the `form`. You can also use `lostfocus` event on all the fields to validate value inside.

Comment: https://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/

Answer (score 0):

Add the other two validation similarly. Just add return after the alert.

Comment: Would it be like this: `$('#dnn_ctr503_DynamicForms_lnkSave').on('mouseover',function()
{
    if( $('#dnn_ctr503_DynamicForms_TBR_GUID35b841a2-5019-4cb0-9041-1204c90e5bebEmail').val().length === 0 ) {
        alert('warning');
    }
return
});
`

Comment: oh so you want to keep the validation code common for all three input fields? If yes then instead of id give class like `$('.dnn_DynamicForms_lnkSave_class').on('mouseover'` and same kind of check will work for all 3 fields.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I haven`t got access to the source files, so I can not add 'required'. I will need to extend my code somehow with comas or adding extra code. I have tried the following:

```
$('#dnn_ctr503_DynamicForms_lnkSave').on('mouseover',function()
{
    if( $('#dnn_ctr503_DynamicForms_TBR_GUID35b841a2-5019-4cb0-9041-1204c90e5bebEmail, #dnn_ctr503_DynamicForms_TBR_GUIDaa4a3017-b28d-46d2-ae6e-7d56b2b886c5Name, #dnn_ctr503_DynamicForms_TBR_GUIDfb4cb1b0-30b9-475f-bb92-7c3d35275e55Message').val().length === 0 ) {
        alert('Please fill in all required fields(*)!');
    }
});`
```

But it doesn`t seem to be working with 3 fields in this way.

Comment: `$('#button_lnkSave').on('mouseover',function()
{
    if( $('#Name').val().length === 0 ) {
        alert('Please fill in all required fields(*)!');  
    } 
  if( $('#Email').val().length === 0 ) {
        alert('Please fill in all required fields(*)!');  
    }
 if( $('#').val().length === 0 ) {
        alert('Please fill in all required fields(*)!');  
    } 
});`

Comment: I am having 3 if conditions at the moment, but I would like it to be one condition to check if any of these 3 fields are empty and show the alert message only once, at the moment it pops up 3 times